# Why I'm getting Unknown error with status 0 - Angular Universal?

Tags: angular, .net-core, iis, angular-universal

I'm getting below error in **10 %** of my requests on production env.

```
"error": "[ProgressEvent]",
"headers": "[ti]",
"message": "Http failure response for https://api.xxxxxx:5000/api/public-web/files: 0 Unknown Error",
"name": "HttpErrorResponse",
"ok": false,
"status": 0,
"statusText": "Unknown Error",
"url": "https://api.xxxxxx:5000/api/public-web/files"
```

Logs are from **Sentry**.
**Stack:**

- **Angular 15 - Universal**
- **.Net Core 6**
- Server: **IIS 10**

Firstly, I was thinking an issue is related to the **CORS** but although that I had already configured **CORS** on backend side, I've also added following to all response headers on the server in `web-config (IIS)`:

```
access-control-allow-headers: *
access-control-allow-methods: GET,POST,PATCH,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: *
```

I've covered CORS just on the IIS with above custom headers in web.config, not on the application side.

Also I've read that it might be related to the bad internet connection (as per Angular official documentation) but that is not an issue here (maybe but just in 1% of 10% of cases).

Users have tried to change their network connection from **WIFI** to **mobile** but still the same issue appears.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at similar thread about CORS issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31612931/cors-issue-on-localhost-while-calling-rest-service-from-angularjs

Comment: @YurongDai On my side it's not happening on the localhost but on production env.
Should not be due to CORS, because as I said I've added custom headers in IIS configuration (web-config).

Comment: Open the website, try to reproduce the problem and check your browser's console for error messages.

Comment: @YurongDai I've tried that many times, from many different browsers and devices (BrowserStack) and I still didn't succeed to reproduce an issue.
For Log Management I'm using Sentry and I've attached the logs that I'm getting (Uknown error (ProgressEvent)).

Comment: I don't want to catch you off-guard, but I've noticed that there's some problems after deploying an ASP.NET Core + Angular + Universal project in release configuration. Still trying to figure this out. It's odd since my project (deployed some time ago) still runs fine...

Comment: @Pieterjan Me to... Still it's happenning randomly and now I'm again suspect it's a CORS issue even it should not be since it's working for 90%+ of users, but how knows..

Comment: For us, it is impossible to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced this same situation. Angular + CORS properly configured + lots of Sentry issues with "HTTP 0 Unknown Error".

You're on the right track. This happens when some users have spotty/bad internet/Wi-Fi connections causing some requests to fail.

I've managed to decrease these errors, and consequently improve UX, by implementing a retry interceptor that retries those failed requests:

```
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { retry, timer } from 'rxjs';

// These variables have to stay outside the class because of 'this' keyword binding issues
const maxRetries = 2;
const delayMs = 2000;

@Injectable()
export class RetryInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler) {
    // Pass the request to the next request handler and retry HTTP 0 errors 2 times with a 2-second delay
    return next.handle(request).pipe(retry({ count: maxRetries, delay: this.delayNotifier }));
  }

  delayNotifier(error: any, retryCount: number) {
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 0) {
      return timer(delayMs);
    }

    // re-throw other errors for anything else that might be catching them
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Even with this retry interceptor, you will always have some of these errors because, well, we can't control the users' internet connections :)